# Cipher Key convert type problems (Power Query)

Tags: type-conversion, key, powerquery, m

I'm trying to do a fonction who basically replace numbers by other things.

Here what I've done so far :

```
 (V2 as text) =>
 
 let
     CipherKey = 
       {
       {0,"µ"},
       {1,"@"},
       {2,"¤"},
       {3,"#"},
       {4,"|"},
       {5,"a"},
       {6,"£"},
       {7,"%"},
       {8,"§"},
       {9,"~"}
       }
 
 in
     Text.Combine(List.ReplaceMatchingItems(Text.ToList(V2),CipherKey))
```

The problem is when ever I'm adding this in another table as a new columns, I'm still getting everytime "Error : can't convert Number into text"

I've tried to add a "Number.ToText" on the last line, doesn't change a thing.

Do you guys have any clues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the answer :

```
(Num_V2 as number) =>

let
    Num_V2 = Number.ToText(Num_V2)
in

let
    CipherKey = 
      {
      {"0","µ"},
      {"1","@"},
      {"2","¤"},
      {"3","#"},
      {"4","|"},
      {"5","a"},
      {"6","£"},
      {"7","%"},
      {"8","§"},
      {"9","~"}
      }

in

    Text.Combine(List.ReplaceMatchingItems(Text.ToList(Num_V2), CipherKey))
```